# Why is AFNetworking turning my Number NSArray to a String NSArray

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have a pretty simple geo array of 2 values [longitude, latitude];

I'm converting it from a CLLocation by doing this

```
NSArray *geoArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat: location.coordinate.longitude], [NSNumber numberWithFloat: location.coordinate.latitude]];
```

I post this data through AFNetworking 2.0 with the default JSON serializers. However, it's aggressively turning my NSNumber array into an NSString Array.

I should really see something like:

```
 {geo: [42, -72]}
```

Instead I'm seeing

```
 {geo: ["42", "-72"]}
```

Comment: What does the raw JSON look like?

Comment: "{"geo":["42","-72"]}"

Comment: Your JSON contains string for what you think are numbers. That's because of the quotation marks. You can either fix your API to send you back numbers, or extract numbers from those string manually from the dictionary.